# How do I pass data from my UWP app to fields on a webpage

Tags: html, web, uwp

I am trying to make a simple app that will take basic information like name, phone number and email address use it to fill out the fields on a webpage. I know it seems simple but my brain is stuck here.

Comment: Are you asking how to have a UWP App "A" talk to the contents of a web page inside of (e.g.) Chrome?

Comment: Yes. Or Firefox or IE. For example this [link](http://www.whitepages.com/reverse_phone) asks for a phone number. How would I make an app that would populate the phone number field for that website

Comment: You'd write an extension for that browser. LastPass is an example. Even though they have Windows store app, you still need to use their extension for Edge or Chrome, etc. You are describing a conceptually simple problem, but it is largely infeasible from an implementation perspective.

Comment: Another option is to load the desired page in a WebView control, then use `InvokeScriptAsync` to inject script into the page which populates the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this library: https://github.com/AngleSharp/AngleSharp

one of its key features is: Form submission (easily log in everywhere) which means it can be used to fill out HTML forms and submit them to the server.

What you will have to do is collect the info using your apps' UI and then use this library to pass the data to the webpage form, then submit.